# Flot select area on IE on centered page

Tags: css, flot

If I try to center my page by adding the following style rule

```
html, body {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 900px;
}
```

Flot works well on FireFox and Chrome, but on IE 11, when I select area on the screen, the yellow-marked-selected-area is not the same as the mouse-selected-area.

How can I solve it?

**To reproduce**: take Flot selection sample - http://www.flotcharts.org/flot/examples/zooming/index.html
and add the style rule for centering.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

have you try by centering .container instead of html and body ?

form example

**CSS**

```
html,body {
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
.container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 900px;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Document Title</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <!--your element place here-->
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: to override defaults I need to add width rule:

html, body {
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  width: auto;
}

Comment: i think you no need to add width:auto to the html, body its by default i think

Comment: its my suggestion to always use normalize css in every project to reset all by default properties https://github.com/necolas/normalize.css/

Comment: width autu is the default, but I have css file that overrides it. and now I need to override this css file . . .